# firefox mobile html height is away smaller than the window height

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, responsive-design, window

I'm facing a problem of window height is away larger than the html height. The HTML height is correct (about 650px) but the window height is about 1600px which creates a big gab after the footer. Inside document ready in the footer:

```
var htmlH=$("html").height(),
    htmlW=$("html").width(),
    windowH=$(window).height();
alert(htmlH);
window.resizeTo(htmlW,htmlH);
```

But the height does not change at all and the gab is still there after the footer. Here's the webpage http://harmony.com.sa/ (on a mobile device using firefox but on desktop this gab does not exist and the page looks just fine) but on chrome this problem does not exist. the widow width is 320px or more just like iPhone. Is there any way to set the window height to be equal to the HTML height that works?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Firefox ignores Viewport completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122910/mobile-firefox-ignores-viewport-completely)